# Is it possible to delete SEDE queries from our account history?

Tags: support, data-explorer

As the title says. There's a history of all our queries and it would be good to be able to delete the lousy queries and keep the useful ones.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @rene I did search for it

Comment: I don't blame you, I live in the [tag:data-explorer] tag ... I know the pending FR's from the top of my head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's currently no way to do this, but it makes sense as a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). 
Since SEDE is partially community-maintained, a volunteer might develop this feature so that it skips the rather long backlog of the Stack Overflow development team.

My workaround is simple: if I know I'm going to write a lousy query, I just don't log in.

Comment: I've written a query so bad, I can't even remember what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: Don't drink and SEDE ... :P

Comment: No, no, Do drink coffee and SEDE :D